# What software exists to record into BWF on a Mac?

Tags: audio-recording, mac

As an alternate solution to [lining up my podcast tracks](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/how-do-i-line-up-multiple-tracks-to-a-master-track-in-audition) I've discovered that Audition has the capability of [inserting BWF files into the multitrack environment by timecode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/audition/cs/using/WS58a04a822e3e5010548241038980c2c5-7fc0.html#WS58a04a822e3e5010548241038980c2c5-7fb5). My thinking is that so long as the clocks on each of the computers are synchronized (i.e. via NTP to the same server) then the resulting timecodes on the local recordings will enable me to skip the step of lining up the files.

However, I've had a difficult time finding affordable software that will record into BWF - it seems mainly to be produced by hardware recorders or very expensive DAW software. What are my options for affordable BWF recording on a Mac?

Comment: Motu's [Digital Performer 7](http://www.motu.com/products/software/dp/session.html) can record BWF, but I'm not sure whether you consider the $395 competitive upgrade affordable.

Comment: @Friend Yeah, that falls under "very expensive DAW software". From what I've read, BWF is just WAV with a header, surely there's *something* out there that can generate such a file simply and cheaply?